# Verifying $\ln(1 + e^{2x}) = 2x + \ln(1 + e^{-2x})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The book is simply asking me to show that this equation is true:

$$\ln(1 + e^{2x}) = 2x + \ln(1 + e^{-2x})$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website.

Comment: well  $2x  = \ln e^{2x}$ so does $\ln(1+e^{2x}) = \ln e^{2x} + \ln (1+e^{-2x})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln(1 + e^{2x}) = 2x + \ln(1 + e^{-2x})$$
Exponentiate both sides, i.e., raise $e$ to these powers on either side
$$(1 + e^{2x}) = e^{2x} \cdot (1 + e^{-2x})=(e^{2x}+1) $$
okay

Answer (score 1):

$$ 1 + e^{2x}  = e^{2x} \left( 1 + e^{-2x}\right)  $$
Which is true.

Truth is just truth. You can't have opinions about truth.

The first two and a half minutes of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MOAtq91idk

Answer (score 1):

Write

$\ln(1 + e^{2x}) = 2x + \ln(1 + e^{-2x})\\
\Leftrightarrow \ln(1 + e^{2x}) - \ln(1 + e^{-2x})= 2x \\
\Leftrightarrow \ln(\frac{1 + e^{2x}}{1 + e^{-2x}})= 2x 
$

and exponentiate on both sides to obtain

$\frac{1 + e^{2x}}{1 + e^{-2x}}=e^{2x}\\
\Leftrightarrow 1 + e^{2x}=(1 + e^{-2x})e^{2x}=1 + e^{2x}$

which is true for all x in $\mathbb{R}$ or even $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: note that 
$$1+e^{-2x} = \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}}$$ 
and use $\ln\bigg{(}\frac{a}{b}\bigg{)} = \ln a - \ln b$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $\quad \ln a + \ln b = \ln(a+b), \quad \ln a^n = n\ln a, \quad \ln e = 1, \quad a^na^m=a^{n+m}, \quad a^{0}=1, a \neq 0$

So, we can write: $$2x = \ln e^{2x}$$

Thus, we have: 
$$\ln(1+e^{2x})= 2x + \ln(1+e^{-2x}) \\$$
$$\iff \ln(1+e^{2x})= \ln e^{2x} + \ln(1+e^{-2x})$$
$$\iff \ln(1+e^{2x})= \ln e^{2x}(1+e^{-2x})$$
$$\iff \ln(1+e^{2x})= \ln (e^{2x}+e^{0})$$
$$\iff \ln(1+e^{2x})= \ln (e^{2x}+1)$$